# ASP .NET WebAPI can't access route

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a basic ASP .NET WebAPI project. There is a `PdfFileController`:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/pdffile")]
public class PdfFileController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<dynamic> Upload(dynamic uploadedData)
    {
        List<object> files = uploadedData.pdfs;
        // ...
    }
}
```

And on the client side I have a POST request using [Oboe](http://oboejs.com):

```
oboe({
    url: this.props.configuration.rootApiUrl + 'pdffile/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    body: { pdfs: pdfs }
}).node('pdfsAsImages.*', function(pdf){ // This callback will be called every time a new pdf image comes in
    channel.pub('pdf.converted', pdf);
});
```

The POST request URL resolves to http://localhost:49706/api/pdffile/upload. From this request, I receive this message:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:49706/api/pdffile/upload
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49706/api/pdffile/upload.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 405.

My static html and js files are being served from a local simple python file server at localhost:8000.

Hitting http://localhost:49706/api/pdffile/upload with Postman returns this:

> {
>     "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
>     "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Object' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
>     "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>     "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
>   }

So there may be several issues going on here. My question is what must I do to overcome the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" problem? It seems to me it has something to do with having the multiple servers, one for static file serving and one for routes. I want to maintain this setup.

Comment: You might want to [enable CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) on the server application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow CORS (cross domain request) try specifying in your webapiconfig.cs/Register

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This requires the Microsoft.AspNet.Cors NuGet package.